# R Markdown flexdashboard - Change placement of data table

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I would like my R Markdown output all the way at the left once I knit to HTML instead it to be centered in the middle. I can't seem to find how to do such a thing.

Below is a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
DT::datatable(iris)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: add more info**

In your yaml header, the `html_document` output sits before `flex_dashboard`, so `html_document` is the default output when you `Knit`.

You can select `Knit to flex_dashboard` in the `knit` dropdown menu.

---

I think you need this: [layout control of flex_dashboard](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/)

In your case, try this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column{data-width=50}
---------------------------------

### Chart 1

```{r, echo = FALSE}
DT::datatable(iris)
```

Column{data-width=50}
---------------------------------

### Chart 2

```{r}

```
````

Comment: Your code worked for me. I did not use any of the `Column{data-width=50}` tough. The thing that made in work was the fact that the `flexdashboard` argument comes before the `html_document` argument, where I had it the opposite way. Do you (or anyone else) know why it works like that?

Comment: If you want to edit your answer so it is clear what the solution was (in my case, see comment) I will accept your answer.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: hi @StanZutt,  when `flexdashboard::flexdashboard` and `html_document` output options are both specified in the yaml header, it means that both output are available for this document. Which, In your case, is the default html_document. You can select flex_dashboard  in the dropdown menu.